# VueJS: Display filtered array list

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, vue.js, filter

I have created an array called *authors*, and the array has 10 objects in them. Each object has a *name* property (String), a *birthYear* property (Number), and a *deceased* property (Boolean). So far, I am able to display the array as a list. What I am trying to do now is:

1. Display a list of the objects with the deceased property as **true** without duplicating the original array
2. Display a list of the objects with the deceased property as **false** without duplicating the original array
3. Display the **sum** of all the numbers for each list and display it at the bottom of the list

In an attempt to achieve the first and second tasks, I have created computed functions named *deceasedAuthors* and *livingAuthors*, but the error that I'm receiving in the console is this:

> vue:634 [Vue warn]: Property or method "deceasedAuthors" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property. See: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties.

This is my Javascript code (app.js):

```
var app = new Vue({
el: '#example-1',
data: {
    authors: [
        {
            name: 'Edgar Allan Poe',
            birthYear: 1809,
            deceased: true
        },
        {
            name: 'Dr. Seuss',
            birthYear: 1896,
            deceased: true
        },
        {
            name: 'Margaret Atwood',
            birthYear: 1939,
            deceased: false
        },
        {
            name: 'Robert Frost',
            birthYear: 1874,
            deceased: true
        },
        {
            name: "Alice Walker",
            birthYear: 1944,
            deceased: false,
        },
        {
            name: "J.K. Rowling",
            birthYear: 1965,
            deceased: false,
        },
        {
            name: "Jonathan Swift",
            birthYear: 1745,
            deceased: true,
        },
        {
            name: "George R.R. Martin",
            birthYear: 1948,
            deceased: false,
        },
        {
            name: "Jane Austen",
            birthYear: 1817,
            deceased: true,
        },
        {
            name: "Stephen King",
            birthYear: 1809,
            deceased: false,
        }
     
    ]
}, computed: {
    deceasedAuthors() {
      console.log("Deceased authors working")
        return this.authors.filter(dead => {
          console.log(dead.deceased)    
            dead.deceased = true  
        })
    }
  },

computed: {
    livingAuthors() {
      console.log("Living authors working")
        return this.authors.filter(dead => {
          console.log(dead.deceased)    
            dead.deceased = false  
        })
    }
  }})
```

This is my HTML code (index.html):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
</head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
<body>
   <h1>Authors</h1>
    <div id="app">
        <ol>
            <li v-for="author in authors">
                {{ author.name }},
                {{ author.birthYear }},
                {{ author.deceased }}
            </li>
        </ol><br><br>

        <ol>
            <li v-for="authorr in deadAuthors">
                {{ authorr.name }},
                {{ authorr.birthYear }},
                {{ authorr.deceased }}
            </li>
        </ol><br><br>

        <ol>
            <li v-for="authorrr in deceasedAuthors">
                {{ authorrr.name }},
                {{ authorrr.birthYear }},
                {{ authorrr.deceased }}
            </li>
        </ol>
       
    </div><br><br>

    <ul id="example-1">
        <li v-for="author in deceasedAuthors">
          {{ author.name }}
        </li>
    </ul>
    
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body></html>
```

Does anyone have any idea on how to make this happen?

Answer (score 0):

You should only have 1 computed object. This can have multiple computed properties inside:

```js
computed: {
  deceasedAuthors() {return ...},
  livingAuthors() {return ...},
}
```

These can be shortened to this:

```js
  computed: {
    alive() {
      return this.authors.filter(author => !author.deceased)
    },
    deceased() {
      return this.authors.filter(author => author.deceased)
    }
  },
```

You can get the number of objects in an array using .length:

```js
alive.length
deceased.length
```

Here is a fully working example: [Vue SFC Playground](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)

```js
<template>
  <div>
    Alive
  </div>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="(author, key) in alive" :key="key">
        {{author.name}} - {{author.birthYear}}
    </li>
    <li>Total: {{alive.length}}</li>
  </ul>
  <div>
    Deceased
  </div>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="(author, key) in deceased" :key="key">
        {{author.name}} - {{author.birthYear}}
    </li>
    <li>Total: {{deceased.length}}</li>
  </ul>
</template>

<script>
import { defineComponent } from "vue";
export default defineComponent({
  computed: {
    alive() {
      return this.authors.filter(author => !author.deceased)
    },
    deceased() {
      return this.authors.filter(author => author.deceased)
    }
  },
  data(){
    return {
       authors: [
        {
            name: 'Edgar Allan Poe',
            birthYear: 1809,
            deceased: true
        },
        {
            name: 'Dr. Seuss',
            birthYear: 1896,
            deceased: true
        },
        {
            name: 'Margaret Atwood',
            birthYear: 1939,
            deceased: false
        },
        {
            name: 'Robert Frost',
            birthYear: 1874,
            deceased: true
        },
        {
            name: "Alice Walker",
            birthYear: 1944,
            deceased: false,
        },
        {
            name: "J.K. Rowling",
            birthYear: 1965,
            deceased: false,
        },
        {
            name: "Jonathan Swift",
            birthYear: 1745,
            deceased: true,
        },
        {
            name: "George R.R. Martin",
            birthYear: 1948,
            deceased: false,
        },
        {
            name: "Jane Austen",
            birthYear: 1817,
            deceased: true,
        },
        {
            name: "Stephen King",
            birthYear: 1809,
            deceased: false,
        }
     
    ]
    }
  }
});
</script>
```